# Domain mapping breaks some plugin scripts and css

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping, scripts, paths

**Here is the context:**
I have a sub domains wp mu install with wp-content in a different location and using the domain mapping plugin. WP and all my plugins are up to date. There is no https involved.

**The problem:**
Some plugins are not working properly (Metaslider, Google Analytics to Dashboard), enqueue JS and css paths are wrong. It seems to always appear when plugins use : `define( 'RANDOMNAME', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );`.

Url without domain mapping :
http://bcwp.guillaumemolter.me/wp-app-content/plugins/google-analytics-dashboard-for-wp/front/css/item-reports.css?ver=4.8.1.2

Url with domain mapping :
http://blackcake-whiteplate.comp/front/css/item-reports.css?ver=4.8.1.2

Everything works perfectly without the domain mapping.

I also tried to force define in my wp-config but it doesn't change anything:

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-app-content' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/wp-app-content' );
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-app-content/plugins' );
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/wp-app-content/plugins' );
```

Any Suggestions??

**wp-config**

```
<?php

/* Local settings contains DB Credentials, SALTS and the DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE */
if(file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . 'local-settings.php')){
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . 'local-settings.php');   
}
else{
    die(dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . "local-settings.php is missing, please read the repo's readme.md");
}

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each a unique
 * prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'molterwpmu_';


/** Relocating the wp-content folder out of wordpress  */

define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-app-content' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/wp-app-content' );

define( 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-app-content/plugins' );
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/wp-app-content/plugins' );

/** Disabling file editing from the admin  */

define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);

/** Network setup  */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

/** Domain mapping  */
define( 'SUNRISE', 'on' );

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

**htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) wp-app/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ wp-app/$1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, adding this to my wp-config.php:

> define( 'PLUGINDIR', 'wp-app-content/plugins' );

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/domain-mapping-breaks-some-plugin-scripts-and-css